# SharePoint 2010 Custom List Form Tool Tip

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

SharePoint 2010 Custom List Form Tool Tip Field Help

I have a custom form in SharePoint and I need to add to formatted field help on mouseover, what is a good way to accomplish this?

STandard tooltips go away to fast.

Oh, by the way, we are NOT using InfoPath we are using SharePoint designer.   We use to use Overlib but can't get it to work with SharePoint code.

Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

We can use jQuery Tooltip from jQuery UI to achieve it. The code below for your reference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("input[title='Title']").tooltip();
})
</script>
```

Add the code to a content editor web part in the custom form page. This code works for the Title field, you can add similar code to make it works for other fields.

Comment: Put the code into a content editor web part in the custom form page, or put the code int "PlaceHolderMain" control below using SharePoint designer.